# How to make sketch-like wiring diagram

Tags: pcb, schematics, design, wiring

I am wondering how to draw such connection diagram in sketch-like style as on belowe picture? I have designed some boards in KiCad and I would like to make wiring around my PCBs in style similar to such one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> *I have designed some boards in KiCad and I would like to make wiring
> around my PCBs in style similar to such one.*

Export PCB step files from KiCAD and import them into FreeCAD is my preferred approach. You get this type of image: -

[image]

Alternatively, you can show a much nicer image of your circuit board in KiCAD's 3D viewer then, copy the preferred image into something like paint for superimposing the wiring stuff: -

[image]